# How to connect the UI and business logic

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, user-interface

I won't describe the project details or the framework I am using because the question is more general.

What is the best way to create flexible interaction between the user interface and the logic.
I am struggling because constantly it turns out that I have to make some feature available for the user to change via some ui but the code for the feature is somewhere deep deep in the code so I have to do lots of refactoring.

What is your approach in such situation? Maybe to model event based system where events are dispatched/handled? In my case the requirements change very often.

Comment: What you are asking is a design decision? I don't think anyone can answer that without seeing the actual problem that you are facing. Please be more specific on your question otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a MVx design pattern such as [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter), [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).

Basically:
* UI should not call BL.
* UI should raise events (or better yet, use commands).
* UI-raised-events/commands should be handled outside UI and call BL.
* BL should not call UI.
* Either modified data should raise events or BL should raise events.
* UI should know how to present data (preferably uses composition to present any type of data and not have entire UI rely on data types not changing).
* UI should refresh on events.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends alot on your application. If its a webapplication the framework you are using probably have some best-practices on how to connect the UI code with buisness logic (Spring @MVC for instance).

On the other hand if you are writing a desktop application, what I usually do is use the obserever/observable pattern to have my UI code get notified of any changes to the underlying model. Again the approach to use varies with the context of the application.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have an example on how to use the observer pattern in combination with winforms? Maybe a link or some sample code?

Comment: I have not used WinForms that much, but I think that Events in .Net is pretty much what you are looking for. Check out this tutorial (and the links to further resources in it) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx